# Clarity about map_chr() function in dplyr and mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am sorry, the functional programming "loops" got me a bit in of head scratching about `purrr`.

I know that to use own, non-vectorised functions one can use `map_chr()` and I used it together with `mutate` to produce 2 new columns. But at one point I did not understand if map_chr every time takes the whole column and produces list output every time or just takes the one value and places that one computed output value in the new variable. Basically - if for every variable in the `SHASUM` column the map_chr returns just one value, or a list of values from which the correct value is automagically picked? I am sorry the question is so fuzzy, but I found it hard to understand, not knowing what is going on inside `pipes` and `mutate`.

My example code below.

**Is this a valid/correct use of map_chr()** (and more generally map functions from purrr) or is there something better that I should have done?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(urlshorteneR)

longLinkBase <- "https://lime.survey.server/334443?newtest=Y?&QID="

initData <- structure(list(SHASUM = c("4db194d", "44fc459", "eb81eb4", "3c37606", "1165fc2", "fd4f56b"), StartDate = c(44172L, 44172L, 44172L, 44172L, 44172L, 44172L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
# convert Excel date serial number into proper date 
initData$StartDate <- as.Date(initData$StartDate, origin = "1899-12-30")

getlongLink <- function(x,y){
  # combine long link base with the (subject) code 
  z <- URLencode(paste0(y,x))
  return(z)
}

getShortLink <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  z <- isgd_LinksShorten(x)
  return(z)
}

# 3 Lines below are my question, really:
initData <- initData %>% 
  mutate(longLink = map_chr(SHASUM,getlongLink,y=longLinkBase))  %>% 
  mutate(shortLink = map_chr(longLink,getShortLink))

### Write out data as CSV file
write.csv(initData,file=paste0("./output/","shortLinks_",format(Sys.time(),"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M_%b"),".csv"),na="")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map_chr` is a hidden loop. The benefit of using it is the code can be piped/chained together and it is better for readability.

`map_chr(SHASUM,getlongLink,y=longLinkBase)` is same as doing -

```
getlongLink(initData$SHASUM[1], longLinkBase)
getlongLink(initData$SHASUM[2], longLinkBase)
getlongLink(initData$SHASUM[3], longLinkBase)
.....
.....
```

The difference is that you don't 'see' these individual calls and they are performed under the hood in `map_chr`. Each of this call returns a single value which is stored as a new column.

I think your code overall is good, I can suggest only one small improvement that you can combine the two `mutate` call into a single one.

```
initData <- initData %>% 
  mutate(longLink = map_chr(SHASUM,getlongLink,y=longLinkBase),
         shortLink = map_chr(longLink,getShortLink))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I did not know that it was possible to do it in one `mutate` call; theoretically - can you put as many columns (at least some depending on previous ones) as needed in one call?

Comment: Yes, as you can see here we are referring to `longLink` from the previous call to create `shortLink` in the same `mutate` call. You can add as many columns as you like here.